# I need to encode a message from an input in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding

So i have to encode a message but it's a different encoding, if the input is `CAT` the output must be `DQ6` it's supposed to encode changing every letter of the input into the upper left key on the keyboard, for example again: `in: bear` `out: G3Q4`. I tried to code this in dictionaries like this:

`d1 = {"q": 1,"Q": 1,"w": 2,"W": 2,"e": 3,"E": 3,"r": 4,"R": 4,"t": 5,"T": 5,"y": 6,"Y": 6,"u": 7,"U": 7,"i": 8,"I": 8,"o": 9,"O": 9,"p": 0,"P": 0}`

`d2 = {"a": 'Q',"A": 'Q',"s": 'W',"S": 'W',"d": 'E',"D": 'E',"f": 'R',"F": 'R',"g": 'T',"G": 'T',"h": 'Y',"H": 'Y',"j": 'U',"J": 'U',"k": 'I',"K": 'I',"l": 'O',"L": 'O',"ñ": 'P',"Ñ": 'P'}`

`d3 = {"z": 'A',"Z": 'A',"x": 'S',"X": 'S',"c": 'D',"C": 'D',"v": 'F',"V": 'F',"b": 'G',"B": 'G',"n": 'H', "N": 'H',"m": 'J',"M": 'J',",": 'K',".": 'L',"-": 'Ñ'}`

I tried this function to check for every key but everything i'm getting is "None" as the value.

```
text = input("Text: ")
def cif(text):
    cifrd = ""
    for i in text:
        if i in d1:
            cifrd += d1[(d1.index(i))%(len(d1))]
        elif i in d2:    
            cifrd += d2[(d2.index(i))%(len(d2))]
        elif i in d3:    
            cifrd += d3[(d3.index(i))%(len(d3))]
        else:
            cifrd += i
print("New text: ",cif(cifrd))
```

Appreciate any help.

[image: This is the outputs i'm getting]

Comment: `return cifrd` in `def cif(text):`.

Comment: I tried now in the outputs is nothing, like: 
`Text: Bear`
`New text:`
Is nothing coming out of it :(

Comment: 1) you need to return the "encoded" text at the end of the `cif()` function, 2) you need to pass `text` to the `cif()` function, `cifrd` is not defined outside your function, 3) dictionaries do not have an `.index()` method. Why aren't you simply accessing the dictionary mapping directly? `d1["q"] -> 1`.

Comment: Well im kinda new into Python, could you help with that 3rd, what are you saying about "mapping directly", like how could i do that into my code? thanks in adv.

Comment: A dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs. If you have a key `"q"` whose value is `1` (as seen in `d1`), then to get the `1` from the `"q"` you just need `d1["q"]`.

Comment: Oh okey, but if it is a long `str` like BEAR how could i map that in just operation? Like in the `for` how would i put that just to map and to keep reading the total input?

Comment: You iterate just like you were. The point is that you don't need to do `d1[(d1.index(i))%(len(d1))]`, you just need `d1[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encoding:

```
d1 = {"q": 1,"Q": 1,"w": 2,"W": 2,"e": 3,"E": 3,"r": 4,"R": 4,"t": 5,"T": 5,"y": 6,"Y": 6,"u": 7,"U": 7,"i": 8,"I": 8,"o": 9,"O": 9,"p": 0,"P": 0}

d2 = {"a": 'Q',"A": 'Q',"s": 'W',"S": 'W',"d": 'E',"D": 'E',"f": 'R',"F": 'R',"g": 'T',"G": 'T',"h": 'Y',"H": 'Y',"j": 'U',"J": 'U',"k": 'I',"K": 'I',"l": 'O',"L": 'O',"ñ": 'P',"Ñ": 'P'}

d3 = {"z": 'A',"Z": 'A',"x": 'S',"X": 'S',"c": 'D',"C": 'D',"v": 'F',"V": 'F',"b": 'G',"B": 'G',"n": 'H', "N": 'H',"m": 'J',"M": 'J',",": 'K',".": 'L',"-": 'Ñ'}
```

There are a few issues. See my comments

```
text = input("Text: ")
def cif(text):
    cifrd = ""
    for letter in text:
        # There is no need to manually write out each dictionary and do a check
        # Put the dictionaries in a list, iterate over each one, and if the letter
        # is in the dictionary, you will get the respective letter back
        for encode in [d1, d2, d3]:
            # check if my letter is in the dictionary
            actual = encode.get(letter)
            # If you check a dictionary and the key is not there, you will get `None`, this if statement ensures you only append actual number/characters
            if actual:
                cifrd += str(actual)
    # When using a function, return something if you need it outside of the function
    return cifrd

decoded = cif(text)
print("New text: {}".format(decoded))
```

Comment: Thank you so so much, this worked as it should. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SERGIOANDRESVALDERRAMAVELEZ please mark one of the provided answers as "accepted" so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code:

1. You need to return the "encoded" text at the end of the `cif()` function
2. You need to pass the `text` variable to the `cif()` function, not `cifrd` which isn't defined outside your function
3. Dictionaries do not have an `.index()` method, you access dictionary items by key, e.g., `d1["q"]` returns `1`.

For what it's worth, there's no need to maintain three separate dictionaries, nor is there reason to maintain both lower- and upper-cased letters in your dictionary; store lower-cased *or* upper-cased keys, and transform the input to the correct case when accessing the translation, i.e., `input "Q" -> lowercase "q" -> d1["q"]`.

Here:

```py
mapping = {'q': 1, 'w': 2, 'e': 3, 'r': 4, 't': 5, 'y': 6, 'u': 7, 'i': 8, 'o': 9, 'p': 0,
           'a': 'q', 's': 'w', 'd': 'e', 'f': 'r', 'g': 't', 'h': 'y', 'j': 'u', 'k': 'i', 'l': 'o', 'ñ': 'p',
           'z': 'a', 'x': 's', 'c': 'd', 'v': 'f', 'b': 'g', 'n': 'h', 'm': 'j', ',': 'k', '.': 'l', '-': 'ñ'}


def cif(s: string) -> string:
    encoded_string = ""
    for char in s:
        encoded_string += mapping.get(char.lower(), char)  # leaves the character un-encoded, if the character does not have a mapping
    return encoded string
```

I would actually suggest using `str.translate()`. You can pass two strings, the first being the input characters, the second being the characters to which those inputs should map:

```py
t = str.maketrans("qwertyuiopasdfghjklñzxcvbnm,.-", "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklñ")


"hello world".translate(t)
'y3oo9 294oe'
```